# Floating footer jquery plugin? (NOT the commonly asked "how to make a footer stick to the bottom of the page")

Tags: jquery, css

NOTE This question is **NOT** the commonly asked "how to make a footer stick to the bottom of the page"

Is there a jquery plugin that *floats* a footer above all other elements if you are not scrolled to it?

This is what my layout looks like:

nav bar

picture

footer 1

text

footer 2

So I want something that will float the footer 1 to the bottom of the viewable screen while you are scrolled to a point above the footer 1 (if you are looking at the nav bar and picture, and footer 1 is normally out of view, I want it to float to the bottom), however, after you scroll past the footer 1, it should go back to normal.

Comment: Sort of like the headers shown on the iOS address book and other locations, but with footers instead of headers?

Comment: yeah basically, when you scroll past them, they display normally fixed in one spot, but before you scroll past them they follow your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have written a plugin which could at least give you an idea on how to accomplish this, check it out at [github](https://github.com/polarblau/stickySectionHeaders).

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I want. Though I conjectured that it wouldn't be very hard to actually program this myself and was just wondering if there was already a plugin to do the job so I don't have to reinvent the wheel. But I can definitely take inspiration since your did a really good job with your plugin. :)